# on check/Uncheck all the child checkboxes should be toggled(checked/unchecked) in recurssive Tree

Tags: prototypejs, prototype

i am trying to implement toggle for checkbox, here when i check/uncheck, all the child checkboxes should be uchecked/Unchecked, this functionality i am trying to add in recurrsive tree below is the part of tree html snippet

```
<strong id="img_18" class="cat_minus" onclick="getchildcategories();"></strong>
<input id="checkbox_18" type="checkbox" onclick="getchildcategories();" value="">
Apparel
<ul>
    <li>
        <strong class="space_filler"></strong> 
        <input id="checkbox_4" type="checkbox" name="product_filter[ProductId][]" onclick="getchildcategories();">
        Shirts
    </li>
    <li id="category_5">
        <strong id="img_5" class="cat_plus" onclick="getchildcategories();"></strong>
        <input id="checkbox_5" type="checkbox" name="product_filter[ProductId][]" onclick="getchildcategories();">
        Shoes
    </li>
    <li>
        <strong class="space_filler"></strong> 
        <input id="checkbox_19" type="checkbox" name="product_filter[ProductId][]" onclick="getchildcategories();"> 
        Hoodies
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the above html i am trying that whecn i check chechbox of id checkbox_18 than all the child checkboxes should be check/uncheked(Toggle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your HTML

```
<strong id="img_18" class="cat_minus" onclick="getchildcategories();"></strong>
<input id="checkbox_18" type="checkbox" onclick="getchildcategories();" value="">
Apparel
<ul>
    <li>
        <strong class="space_filler"></strong> 
        <input id="checkbox_4" class="childof_18" type="checkbox" name="product_filter[ProductId][]" onclick="getchildcategories();">
        Shirts
    </li>
    <li id="category_5">
        <strong id="img_5" class="cat_plus" onclick="getchildcategories();"></strong>
        <input id="checkbox_5" class="childof_18" type="checkbox" name="product_filter[ProductId][]" onclick="getchildcategories();">
        Shoes
    </li>
    <li>
        <strong class="space_filler"></strong> 
        <input id="checkbox_19" class="childof_18" type="checkbox" name="product_filter[ProductId][]" onclick="getchildcategories();"> 
        Hoodies
    </li>
</ul>
```

If you can add a class to the child checkboxes like above then you can control them easily in any observer handler. For Instance

```
$('checkbox_18').observe('click',function(){
    //this is the element the event happened on
    //in this case the element with id checkbox_18
    if(this.checked)
    {
        $$('.childof_18').invoke('writeAttribute','checked','checked');
    }
    else
    {
        $$('.childof_18').invoke('writeAttribute','checked',null);
    }
});
```

If you can't add a class to the child checkboxes - but you know the DOM structure will be consistent you can use the DOM traversal methods to get there. This is how I would do it.

```
$('checkbox_18').observe('click',function(){
    if(this.checked)
    {
        this.next('ul').select('input[type="checkbox"]').invoke('writeAttribute','checked','checked');
    }
    else
    {
        this.next('ul').select('input[type="checkbox"]').invoke('writeAttribute','checked',null);
    }
});
```

Warning: the 2nd method will only work if your structure is consistent with the HTML snippet you provided ie a parent checkbox next to a `<ul>` which contains the child checkboxes.